# Jmeter recording in NON GUI mode for Selenium testing

Tags: scripting, terminal, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I would like to record the network requests of a Selenium test. Rather than using jmeter GUI, I would like to automate this process in a script. The idea would be to run a selenium test and record it simultaneously. Is there a built in way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GUI Jmeter is ideally for development of scripts, which are then run headless to get true performance figures.

You can develop selenium webdriver tests as junit tests, which integrate to JMeter very easily.

Running a recorded Selenium IDE test would not be so straightforward, better to export it as Java Webdriver.

Make sure you follow junit naming conventions and annotations (depending which version you use). Write the test class, including junit 'test' methods, then create a jmeter test plan with a junit sampler, and configure the junit sampler to run your test method[s].

maven and plugins can be used to make it all run seamlessly in headless mode on any host.

Once you have developed one of these, it will be easy to review the jmx test script and automate the process of creating more jmeter tests, if that is what you meant by automating the process.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Start JMeter's Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)
2. Configure your Selenium script to use JMeter as a proxy. See [Using a Proxy](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy) guide for configuration details for each driver
3. Run Selenium test - all requests should be recorded by JMeter.
4. Add the next test elements to JMeter test plan:

   - [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) - to represent browser cookies
   - [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) - to represent browser cache
   - follow recommendations from [How to make JMeter behave more like a real browser](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/115022-how-to-make-jmeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) to properly configure embedded resources retrieval, user agent, request defaults, etc.
5. Configure Thread Group parameters according to your load scenario.
6. Replay the test.

I expect that you will need to apply some [correlation](http://artoftesting.com/performanceTesting/correlation.html), but it may be not required.

Comment: Can a Jmeter proxy server be fired up in a NON GUI mode?